# Python: Fetch data items from a web site

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml and python and scrapping through [THIS](http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10210956518304804392&q=&ved=0CF4QxgdIAQ&sa=X&ei=o8xxT_fEGtjp_Aa7zZnZCw) site. I would like to deal with **two** issues that I am stuck on in the same question.

1. Firstly, I want to fetch the text **X out of Y people found this review helpful** which is under each review
2. Secondly, I want to get the href to the google's **NEXT** button

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `BeautifulSoup` for this? `lxml` is a complexity overkill.

Comment: I heard the opposite, though it's the clients requirement so can't say much

Comment: Also: what have you tried? Can you show us some relevant code? Why do you want this (and is there an alternate way to get it?) Is there an official Google API that will let you access this information without having to scrape it?

Comment: lxml runs much faster then BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Smells to me like premature optimsation. Unless you're sitting on the end of a very, very fat internet connection, a Python script will be able to process data far faster than you can suck it down through the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to scrape the page. Use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/).

Comment: Clients requirement! Please stick to the question :)

Comment: Client requirements be damned. The API is there to make it easier for programmers to get data without having to perform scraping. At the same time, the API is there to save Google the cost of serving up an *entire webpage* just to give you the few pieces of information you want.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see the NEXT button but in terms of figuring out how many stars are there for each review section just have your program count the number of times `class="rsw-stars"` shows up. One of those means one star and five means five stars.

On a side note, google has very advanced anti-scraping tools setup.  As you scape them the system will prompt you to enter letters/numbers to make sure your a human.

Comment: I have delt with the star, in the question I mean the text below each review X out of Y people found this review helpful

Comment: and the Next button is below the Google monogram

Comment: I can't see the google monogram for some reason on the page you linked. But if you use chrome then just right click on area you want to capture and select 'inspect' and you'll see the section of the page that refers to what your after.  If you use firefox then use the firebug plugin for this.

Comment: Not to sound like a broken record but I must agree with Li-aung Yip and Daniel Roseman answer. You can save yourself alot of work by not scraping this. Its not simply from google's perspective(less resources) but yours also as they are constantly trying to block people from doing this and its very likely your code will break after a while but using the API they will notify you of any changes and do so gracefully. Even if its client requirements, you have an obligation to tell let them know this is doomed and purpose a more robust and cleaner solution. Trust me they'll respect you for it.